# V-for doesn't work in nuxt.js, I'm trying to cycle card component

Tags: nuxt.js

[image][image]

Dev tools says me:
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "product". Expected Object, got Array

```
my index page:
```

```
<template>
  <div class="container" v-if="loading">loading...</div>
  <div v-else>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
   
      <product :product="product"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Product from '../components/product.vue';

export default {
  components: { Product },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      products: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.loading = true;
    const response = await this.$axios.$get("/api/products");
    this.products = response;
    this.loading = false;
  },

};
</script>
```

card component:

```
<template>
  <b-card>
  </b-card>

</template>
<script>
export default {
props :{
    product:{
        required: true,
        type:Object
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I m expecting to see two cards
I'm trying to render the card component (bootstrap vue) in my index page taking the data from db, so i have 2 products registered in my db and I should see 2 cards in my page but I see only 1 card As just I'm putting the component

vue dev tools says:

product:Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGULO.png)
0:Object
description:"description"
id:1
img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523275335684-37898b6baf30?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=799&q=80"
name:"product 1"
price:"10.00"
1:Object
description:"descrizione"
id:3
img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
name:"prodotto 2"
price:"12.00"

so there are 2 products in the array vut if I try to change props type in "array" it doesn't work the same

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Please use your Vue devtools to inspect what you do have inside of your `products` and `product` state.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `fetch()` or `asyncData()` lifecycle hooks since you're using Nuxt here.

Comment: Please share `products` too + add an image rather than text, it's not really friendly to read.

Comment: @kissu product is the card component

Comment: `products`, not `product`. You're iterating on an array of arrays maybe.

Comment: @kissu Where I should change product in products?

Comment: As told above, please share an image of your Vue devtools with `products` and `product`, both of them.

Comment: @kissu as u see in photos the array contain 2 elements

Comment: Nice! I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The state `products` is an object, containing `data`.
That one is an array, so the iteration should be

```html
<div v-for="product in products.data" :key="product.id">
```

That way, the `Product` component will contain the desired object.